# CrossCompiling with libboost for ARM architecture

Tags: compiling, c++, arm

I am using a 32 Bit Ubuntu system and my goal is to compile my C++ program for arm architecture (beagleblack). However, my C++ program needs libboost meaning I get errors like this while compiling:

```
/4.7/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld: cannot find -lboost_system
-bash: /usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabi/4.7/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld:: No such file or directory
```

After reading some blogs I think that I have to compile libboost for ARM by myself.

**Question:** 
Is my assumption true? Is there really no precompiled libboost for ARM that can be used with `g++-arm-linux-gnueabi` to compile for ARM under Ubuntu 32 bit?

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu does have a precompiled Boost library for `armhf` (I'm assuming the Beagleblack can use `armhf`). Assuming you'll be using Ubuntu on the Beagleblack, there are two ways you can go about this:

1. Use `pbuilder` or `sbuild` to compile in a chroot of the `armhf` architecture. This would (generally) require that you have Debian packaging for what you want to compile. However, you could (at least in `sbuild`) also start an instance of the chroot, use `apt-get` to get the required libraries, and compile your program in there. `pbuider` is generally easier to set up.
2. Use multiarch to your advantage and install `armhf` libraries on your computer, so you can compile and use existing libraries without using a chroot. To do this, run `sudo dpkg --add-architecture armhf`, and edit `/etc/apt/sources.list` to contain `deb [arch=armel] http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports saucy main universe` (if you aren't using Saucy, replace with the appropriate release. Then, run `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get install libboost-system1.53.0:armhf` (or some other Boost package postfixed with `:armhf`). This will let you have the `armhf` libraries installed on your system under `/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu`.

Note that the second method above will only work for multiarch libraries, which should be most of the libraries in the Ubuntu repo. You may also want to use the second method in a chrooted environment to prevent messing up your system (see [here](http://www.cnx-software.com/2012/05/02/getting-started-with-multiarch-armel-armhf-in-ubuntu/) for instructions that use Precise, which is not multiarch-aware).